# building a tree from left parenthetic string representation

Tags: java

I need to build a right parenthetic representation of a string from left parenthetic representation. Basically this means parsing a String input and later rebuild a right parenthetic representation. I need to implement 2 methods: One that would parse the input and one that creates the needed representation from that parsed input. This is part of a homework I need to do in java.

The code how I would test this:

```
  String s = "A(B1,C)";
  Node t = Node.parse (s);
  String v = t.rightParentheticRepresentation();
  System.out.println (s + " ==> " + v); // A(B1,C) ==> (B1,C)A
```

So i need to implement 2 methods: Node parse(String s) and String rightParentheticRepresentation()

I know in theory I have some idea how I should go on about doing it but I am struggling to implement the parsing method.
Is there any existing implementations I could use? Any hint for implementation approach is very welcome or if someone knows any good tutorial on building trees from string representation.

Comment: @tllsdv checkout this [link](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~ylari/I231/Node.java) it may help

Answer (score 0):

First you should get an idea of the data structure that you want to build. Basically here you want a tree where each node correspond to a content inside some parenthesis (the initial parenthis are implicit - '(' A(B1,C) ')' - in your sample).

For the parsing method: read the input String char by char. Whenever you meet an opening parenthesis '(' you create a child to the current node and change current to the new node, then start filling it. When you meet a closing parenthesis ')' you finalize the current node and come back to its parent.